# NGXS @Selector doesn't update value

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, observable, ngxs

I have an issue with the NGXS Selector.

In my state, I call an API to get a table. Because of unified error handling, I first call the API and then defer the actual handling of the request to a service made for store management like:

```js
@Action(LoadTable)
private loadTable(ctx: StateContext<SomeState>) {
  const state = ctx.getState();
  ctx.patchState({
    table: {
      ...state.table,
      content: emptyTable,
      loading: true
    }
  });

  return this.api.loadTable()
    .pipe(StateUtilService.errorHandlingOperator<SomeState>(
      ctx,
      'table',
      TransformService.tableTransformCallback()
    );
}
```

In my error handling operator, I pass in the store to be able to patch it, then check whether a variable with the according name and type 'table' exists and finally pass the returned data through the `tableTransformCallback` function and save the result via `ctx.patchState()`.

In my selector, I return the contents of the table plain and simple without any additional transformations.

The problem is, that the table loads and ALL of its properties get updated except one. The parameter `totalNumberOfRows` stays 0, taken from the original `emptyTable` object I use when loading (or reloading) the table. When I check the store, it correctly shows the API-loaded number of rows, but the selector ignores the correct value, not passing it through. It messes up the paginator.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: You're return statement with pipable opertor there looks funky to me, seems like you're doing some custom stuff there. But just log the state before and after the update. Maybe the property you're referring to is on some deeply nested object and you need to account for that in your spread operator

Comment: The state acknowledges the change. When using the devTools, I can clearly see the state having the correct number of rows, but it doesn't trigger a new emission from selector, it seems. Which is strange to me, since all the other changes DO get updated.